# How to find "next" element in rendered layout using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery's next() returns the next immediate sibling of an element.
However, how does one find the next *rendered* element, even when that element has different lineage?
For example, consider this (simplistic) HTML:

```
<div id='a'>A
    <div id='b'>B
       <div id='c'>C</div>
    </div>
    <div>D</div>
</div>
```

which renders to something like:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Your eye naturally sees D following C, though in the DOM they're uncle/nephew.

So, how would one find `"D"` given `#c`?

```
var c = $('#c');  // Pretty straightforward
var x = c.someJqFunction(with some params);
```

Note: Pretend you don't know anything about D, other than it exists. It could be the true next sibling of #c, or it could be in a complex traverse from #c. The salient thing is that they are known to be immediately adjacent in the *rendered* output.

Comment: You could recursively check if your current element is the last child, then move up the tree until you have a 'next' element to target.

Comment: can D have an id too?

Comment: Can we assume that it's a div? Then we could use .closest() with the :contains selector.

Comment: **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9ds4ucma/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xa13oq7z/

```
function getNext(id) {
    var elm = $('#' + id);
    return elm.children(':first')[0] || elm.next()[0] || elm.parent().next()[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it

```
$(function(){
console.log($('#c').parent().siblings().html());

});
```

**NOTE:** This is assuming that there is only one sibling for `div` with `id "b"`

Look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLet9dc0/) link

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this do?

```
function getNext(elem){
    var next = elem.next();
    if(next.length){
        if(next.get(0).offsetParent != null){
            return next;
        }else{
            return getNext(next);
        }
    }else{
        return getNext(elem.parent());
    }
}
```